# How to monitoring resources?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy

I have a problem.

I develop an Android application, and the users complain, because the app is slow, reather than, not as fast as before the update.

One of the layouts appears slower than before update. The fragment contains a lot of observers.

So I don,t know why. I would like to monitoring the usages, I found Profiler in android studio, but i don't know what should I see.

Cpu usages always under 70%, and memory usages is about 174 mb max

Comment: Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZffMCJdA5Qc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjmIit_amnE

Comment: Are doing too much on the UI thread? That would make it appear slow. Use dedicated threads for IO and CPU-intensive operations.

Comment: implement firebase performance, so you can get report and monitoring at there

Comment: @Nicolas I don't think that, I'm doung too much work on UI thread, but I use a lot of live data, it can couse this?

Comment: @Michiel Thanks, I watched, but I didn't get smarter, because I don't see datas, which are in the secound video, for example frames, threads etc...

Comment: Finally, I found the problem. We use constraint layout to create dynamic layout, with different layout components. Earlier I updated constraint layout package in gradle, and this coused the problem, I don't know why, I will find out.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but the final solution was that, I downgraded the version of material component. After that, the view loaded in faster.